# SFML Stop or delete clock

Tags: c++, sfml

is it possible to stop or delete clock in SFML ? I'm learning SFML and I did rectangle getting bigger until 4 seconds pass then it resets. But now I'm thinking about doing something similar, but instead of rectangle size reseting I want to leave the size of rectangle which it got in 4 seconds then I want to draw next rectangle next to previous one. But to do this I need to somehow stop created clock or freeze it or the first rectangle will get only bigger. Is it possible to do it ?

```
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1800, 800), " window ");
sf::Clock timer;
while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();

    } //while
    window.clear();

    sf::RectangleShape shape(sf::Vector2f(timer.getElapsedTime().asSeconds()*50,100));


    if (timer.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() > 4)
    {
        timer.restart();

    }



    shape.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(100, 400));

    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color(150,150,150));
    window.draw(shape);
    window.display();
}
```

Comment: Instead of stopping the clock, stop the rectangle from betting bigger then 4*50.

Comment: @super How can I do it ?
I tried one line if-else statement in constructor of shape, but it didn't work then I know why, because it was already created and i have no idea now what to do. It was my code: int example = 0;

  sf::RectangleShape shape(sf::Vector2f((example == 1) ? 200 :timer.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() * 50, 100));


  if (timer.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() > 4)
  {
   example = 1;
   
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it could be like this

```
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1800, 800), " window ");
sf::Clock timer;
sf::RectangleShape shape(sf::Vector2f(timer.getElapsedTime().asSeconds()*50,100));
while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();

    } //while
    window.clear();

    if (shape.getSize().x < 200)
        shape.setSize(sf::Vector2f(std::min(timer.getElapsedTime().asSeconds()*50, 200.f), 100));

    shape.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(100, 400));

    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color(150,150,150));
    window.draw(shape);
    window.display();
}
```

Comment: I got error at line with std::min even when i included <iostream> and namespace std

Comment: and when i don't create shape in window loop i don't see it in window

Comment: seems like timer.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() can't be an argument in std::min

Comment: Need to edit the second argument to std::min so it's also a float. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Now it works, but can I ask you a question, why it's now working perfectly but when i will create shape in window loop instead outside of it like you did, the rectangle lenght won't stop.

Comment: If you create the shape inside the loop, the shape gets destroyed and then recreated on every iteration of the loop. You can do it like that, but it seems like a bad design choice.

Comment: Yes, but its in the window loop, so it should be destroyed when i close the window, not affect something what is being done in the window.

Comment: I will get destroyed every frame, and every frame a new one will be created.